# How to Send Variable to Parent Controller from Directive without Isolate Scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

### How to watch variable from directive in controller AngularJS?

I have a component with controller and directive

In my directive I'm listening for scroll and returning true if element is in view or false if it is not.

I want to be able to accesss my `boolChangeClass` variable in the controller so that I can call my function only if it is true.

My question is how can I access `boolChangeClass` in controller?

```
    'use strict';
    
    angular.module('myModule')
      .component('myComponent', {
        template: `
          <div class="component" inview ng-class="{min: boolChangeClass}">
          </div>
        `,
    
        controller: function ($scope) {
          let $ctrl = this;

          let func = () => {console.log('my function')}

      $scope.$watch('boolChangeClass', func);
    }
  })
  .directive('inview', ($window) => {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
          let rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
          scope.boolChangeClass =  rect.bottom > 0 &&
              rect.right > 0 &&
              rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
              rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
          scope.$apply();
        });
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr;

To send variable to parent controller from a directive that uses `scope:false`:

```
<div on-scroll="$ctrl.fn($event)"></div>
```

```
scope.$apply( () => {
    scope.$eval(attrs.onScroll, {$event: event});
});
```

---

### Answer

Instead of setting the class with `ng-class`, have the directive set the class:

```
<div class="component" inview-class="min"  ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶=̶"̶{̶m̶i̶n̶:̶ ̶b̶o̶o̶l̶C̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶C̶l̶a̶s̶s̶}̶" >
</div>
```

```js
app.directive('inviewClass', ($window) => {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).on("scroll", function(event) {
      let rect = elem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      let boolChangeClass =  rect.bottom > 0 &&
          rect.right > 0 &&
          rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
          rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      let className = attrs.inviewClass;
      boolChangeClass ? elem.addClass(className) : elem.removeClass(className);
    });
  };
})
```

This avoids involving the AngularJS digest cycle, modifying $scope, and adding a watcher.

---

### Update

> And what should I do in my controller? Check if class exists and then call he method?

Use an attribute to specify the function to be called on a scroll event:

```
<div class="component" inview-class="min" on-scroll="$ctrl.fn($event)" >
</div>
```

```js
app.directive('inviewClass', ($window) => {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).on("scroll", function(event) {
      let rect = elem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      let boolChangeClass =  rect.bottom > 0 &&
          rect.right > 0 &&
          rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
          rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      let className = attrs.inviewClass;
      boolChangeClass ? elem.addClass(className) : elem.removeClass(className);
      //
      event.inview = {};
      event.inview[className] = boolChangeClass;
      scope.$apply( () => {
          scope.$eval(attrs.onScroll, {$event: event});
      });
    });
  };
})
```

On each scroll event, the directive will evaluate the `on-scroll` attribute as an AngularJS expression using $event as a local.

---

### Update #2

> But what if I want to call method in controller on scroll but only once when my variable is true? I tried to use one-time binding but it doesn't really work.

It would be wiser to have the controller filter the events:

```
<div class="component" inview-class="min" on-scroll="$ctrl.fn($event)" >
</div>
```

```js
var minOnce;
this.fn = (event) => {
    if (minOnce || !event.inview.min) return;
    //ELSE
    minOnce = true;
    //
    // ...
};
```

This way the directive is more versatile and testing is easier.

Comment: Ok. And what should I do in my controller? Check if class exists and then call he method?

Comment: Thanks. It works great. But what if I want to call method in controller on scroll but only once when my variable is true? I tried to use one-time binding but it doesn't really work.